# Locking orbital controls while using transform controls on multiple meshes

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, drei

I'm trying to have the orbital controls lock their position while I'm transforming either of the meshes in my example. My current implementation follows the logic found here: https://drei.pmnd.rs/?path=/story/controls-transformcontrols--transform-controls-lock-st it currently locks the orbital controls for one of the boxes being moved but not the other. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/mixing-controls-forked-uzmy8?file=/src/App.js

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { OrbitControls, TransformControls } from '@react-three/drei'

function Box() {
  return (
    <mesh>
      <boxGeometry />
      <meshNormalMaterial />
    </mesh>
  )
}

function TransformBox({ position, transform }) {
  return (
    <TransformControls position={position} ref={transform} mode="translate" showZ={false}>
      <Box />
    </TransformControls>
  )
}

function Main() {
  const orbit = useRef()
  const transform = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    const controls = transform.current
    const callback = (event) => (orbit.current.enabled = !event.value)
    controls.addEventListener('dragging-changed', callback)
    return () => controls.removeEventListener('dragging-changed', callback)
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <TransformBox transform={transform} position={[0, 2.5, 0]} />
      <TransformBox transform={transform} />
      <OrbitControls ref={orbit} />
    </>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Canvas dpr={[1, 2]}>
      <Main />
    </Canvas>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { OrbitControls, TransformControls } from '@react-three/drei'

function Box({ active, setActive }) {
  return (
    <mesh
      onClick={() => {
        setActive(!active)
      }}>
      <boxGeometry />
      <meshNormalMaterial />
    </mesh>
  )
}

function TransformBox({ position, orbit }) {
  const transform = useRef()
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (transform.current) {
      const { current: controls } = transform
      const callback = (event) => {
        orbit.current.enabled = !event.value
      }
      transform.current.addEventListener('dragging-changed', callback)
      return () => controls.removeEventListener('dragging-changed', callback)
    }
  })

  return (
    <TransformControls
      showX={active ? true : false}
      showY={active ? true : false}
      position={position}
      ref={transform}
      mode="translate"
      showZ={false}>
      <Box active={active} setActive={setActive} />
    </TransformControls>
  )
}

function Main() {
  const orbit = useRef()

  return (
    <>
      <TransformBox orbit={orbit} />
      <TransformBox orbit={orbit} position={[0, 2.5, 0]} />
      <OrbitControls ref={orbit} />
    </>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Canvas dpr={[1, 2]}>
      <Main />
    </Canvas>
  )
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).